# How to pass an array like string[] to smart contract using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

When I run this, I get

> undefined: symbol attendedStudents

I don't know how to pass string type array to smart contract function.

```
const attendedStudents = [];
    const absentStudents = [];

//I have pushed some values into both the arrays

advancedStorage.methods.setAttendance(acc, $classs, $subject, $date, $attendedStudents, $absentStudents)
  .send({from: activeAccount}).then(result => {
      //someCode
  });
```

My smart contract function

```
function setAttendance(string memory _teacher, string memory _class, string memory _subject, 
    string memory _date, string[] memory _attendedStudents, string[] memory _absentStudents) public {
     //somecode
  }
```

Comment: Now i'm getting "invalid string value (arg="_teacher", coderType="string", value={})", i tried adding $acc, but still same error. acc variable contains "John" value

Comment: I have added pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2; on top of the .sol, but still I'm getting ABICoder errors.

Comment: does it work if you just pass the array directly in the function call without referring to the variable?

Comment: The values in the array are dynamic in nature.